# I purchased a Lutron occupancy sensor MS-OPS5MH-WH. I have no ground available.

Tags: electrical, grounding, motion-sensor

I purchased a Lutron MS-OPS5MH-Wh.  It has 2 black wires one green one blue and one bare.  I hooked up the two black wires but do not have a ground (green and bare).. When hooked up the light is on all the time.  I have read on the net that it will not work without a ground hook-up. Can you help me get this thing to work.

Comment: Is the neutral available in the switch box?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the switch box?

Comment: It's legal to retrofit just a ground wire.  I have seen a trend where dimmers of late want ground and not neutral, which ain't quite right, since they are obviously using it as a current return, which is a no-no... But somehow UL is approving this.   Anyway, I suspect they are erring toward use of ground because it is legal to retrofit ground, but not neutral.